# UICollectionView ItemSelected does not trigger

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

> **This is for Xamarin.iOS**
>
> Sorry for confusion this is not for Objective-C but for C# Xamarin.iOS ,
>   I already had the tags for Xamarin.

It seems like its all over the internet from 2014 that ItemSelected is not triggered on UICollectionView.
Is there a solution to this other than using TouchesBegan, TouchesEnded ?

I also noticed that CellDisplayingEnded() does not trigger either!!

> **Answering my own question:** Instead of setting up a "Source" for the
>   table view , I've set it as a "DataSource" by mistake and those
>   methods were are never called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question. Instead of setting up a "Source" for the table view , I've set it as a "DataSource" by mistake and those methods are never called

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `UICollectionViewDelegate` method,
The `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol defines methods that allow you to manage the selection of items in a collection view. When user selects an item, the collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method is invoked.

```
 -  (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
  }
```

This may help you

Comment: Sorry for confusion this is not for Objective-C but for C# Xamarin.iOS , I already had the tags for Xamarin. ItemSelected() Method is the equivalent to Objective-C didSelectItemAtIndexPath in Xamarin